# Print onclick attribute of several buttons in a webpage

Tags: python, html, selenium, css-selectors

I am trying to get the attribute "onclick" (`onclick="openDirection( 41.051777,28.986551)"`) of the first button element inside all of the li elements. I want to print all the coordinates. In the code above I can manage to print the first two element's coordinates. However, a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown afterwards.

```
driver.get('https://migroskurumsal.com/magazalarimiz/')

try:
    select = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'stores'))
    )
    print('Dropdown is ready!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Took too much time!')

select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'stores'))

select.select_by_value('2')
shopList = driver.find_element(By.ID, "shopList")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='shopList']/li/div/button"))
    )
    print('Shoplist is ready!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Took too much time!')
    driver.quit()

print(shopList.get_attribute("class"))

li_items = shopList.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')

for item in li_items:
    
    first = item.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'div')
    second = first.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
    coord = second.get_attribute("onclick")
    print(coord)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. You are using wrong locators
2. You will need to scroll the page in order to access the elements initially not in the visible view.

This should work better:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver.get('https://migroskurumsal.com/magazalarimiz/')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
try:
    select = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'stores')))
    print('Dropdown is ready!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Took too much time!')

select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'stores'))

select.select_by_value('2')

shopList = driver.find_element(By.ID, "shopList")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='shopList']/li/div/button")))
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Shoplist is ready!')
except TimeoutException:
    print('Took too much time!')
    driver.quit()
li_items = shopList.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.m-bg-cream')
for idx, val in enumerate(li_items):
    li_items = shopList.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.m-bg-cream')
    item = li_items[idx]
    actions.move_to_element(item).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    button = item..find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick^='set']")
    coord = button.get_attribute("onclick")
    print(coord)
```

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for answering. The code you provided prints the attributes of the first two buttons, then throws MoveTargetOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: Are you using ChromeDriver or FireFoxDriver?

Comment: I am using ChromeDriver.